# Table does not update entries after data is loaded into array

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, cocoa-bindings

I have a service that loads data into my table view. When the service has loaded the data I load the data into my model:

```
[self.model.entries removeAllObjects];
[self.model.entries addObjectsFromArray:objects];
```

Now I am wondering if those two calls are "binding compliant" so that the table view will know that it has to update it's data which are directly bound to `self.model.entries`. I am asking this because after the service is done the table does not ask my delegate again for the number of tableviewcells so it seems that the binding does not kick in.

I think I could call `reloadData` on the tableview but this would then no longer conform to the "binding philosophy", right?

Please note that my model class returns a new `NSMutableArray` if it is not present. It is not clear to me if this is the correct approach for using bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full bindings compatibility you should bind through an NSController... in this case, presumably NSArrayController.

By binding directly to the model you are breaking the MVC pattern, and no, I don't believe that the NSTableView will pick up changes when directly bound to the model.

Bind your table view to NSArrayController's arrangedObjects, for example, and use the NSArrayController methods, such as:

```
-add:
-removeObjects:
-insert:
```

to manage the content.  The table view *will* pick up on these changes automatically.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why this breaks the MVC pattern?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat flippantly, because you are omitting the "C" part of MVC. ;-)  The idea is that the model shouldn't know anything about the UI and vice-versa.  If you, for example, switched from backing your data by an array to backing it with a dictionary, database, or web service, your UI shouldn't change - only the glue in the controller.  The framework is trying to nudge you into better architecture, hence the need to bind through a controller.